# CreateTimerQueueTimer termination on WM_CLOSE

Tags: c++, winapi, timer

I have this in a header:

```
static volatile bool g_operational = true;
```

then `WM_CLOSE` has this:

```
g_operational = false;
WaitForSingleObject(TimerDoneEvent , INFINITE);
DeleteTimerQueueEx(t_main , NULL);
```

with the timer callback function looking like this:

```
VOID CALLBACK main_timer(PVOID lpParam , BOOLEAN TimerOrWaitFired) {
    // doing stuff
    if ( !g_operational ) 
        SetEvent(TimerDoneEvent);
}
```

The timer itself is doing what I expect but the issue is shutting it down from `WM_CLOSE`, what's happening is `g_operational` is set to `false` then the timer thread that's running every second should pick up on `g_operational` being false then call `SetEvent` to signal that the thread is done so `WaitForSingleObject` can continue but within the callback function `g_operational` always remains `true`, why is this?

Comment: why this not visible - no code. but why you use `g_operational` and `TimerDoneEvent` at all ? you need by sense use `DeleteTimerQueueTimer` with `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` or `CompletionEvent` instead

Comment: Defining static variables in header files is usually not a good idea.

Comment: @JonathanPotter - yes, every cpp file will be have private copy of it. as result `main_timer`  will be use another `g_operational` variable than `g_operational = false;` but anyway use `g_operational` is error by winapi. need `DeleteTimerQueueTimer`